# Erro : name 'quantidade' is not defined

Tags: python

```
class Posto():
  def __init__(self,quantidade, valor, preco, tipo):
    self.quantidade = quantidade
    self.valor = valor
    self.tipo = tipo
    self.preco = preco

  def abastecer(self):
    self.tipo = input(print("Olá, bem vindo ao posto Sheel, qual será o tipo de combustível? \n"))
    if self.tipo == 'etanol':
      self.preco = input('Qual o valor do litro do etanol? \n')
      self.quantidade = input("Qaual a quantidade que será abastecida? \n")
      self.valor = self.preco *self.quantidade
      print("O abastecimento deu ",self.valor," reais \n")

    elif self.tipo == 'gasolina':
      self.preco = input('Qual o valor do litro da gasolina? \n')
      self.quantidade = input("Qaual a quantidade que será abastecida? \n")
      self.valor = self.preco *self.quantidade
      print("O abastecimento deu ",self.valor," reais \n")

    elif self.tipo  == 'disel':
      self.preco = input('Qual o valor do litro do disel? \n')
      self.quantidade = input("Qaual a quantidade que será abastecida? \n")
      self.valor = self.preco *self.quantidade
      print("O abastecimento deu ",self.valor," reais \n")


abastecimento1 = Posto(quantidade,valor,preco,tipo)

quantidade = abastecimento1.quantidade
valor = abastecimento1.valor
preco = abastecimento1.preco
tipo = abastecimento1.tipo
abastecimento1.abastecer()
```

Comment: Bom dia! Para aumentar as chances de obter ajuda, o ideal é formatar adequadamente seu código. Por outro lado, do que deu pra ler, me parece que você escreveu a função init errado. Tem que ter dois underlines antes e dois depois: ```__init__```.

Comment: Se a colocação dos underlines resolver, foi só um erro de digitação, e isso não teria utilidade para a posteridade -- portanto, você pode excluir a pergunta. Se não resolver, faça o edit na pergunta e veja se alguém pode ajudar.

Answer (score -2):

1º A função 'construtora' do python tem o nome `__init__` e não `init`.

2º A instrução `if` dentro do método abastecer é desnecessária para o cenário da pergunta.

Eu tomei a libertade de altará-la.

```py
class Posto():

    def __init__(self, quantidade: float, valor: float, preco: float, tipo: str) -> None:

        self.quantidade = quantidade
        self.valor: float = valor
        self.preco: float = preco
        self.tipo: str = tipo: str

    def calcular_valor(self, preco: float, quantidade: float) -> float:
        if self.valor:
            return self.valor
        
        self.valor = preco * quantidade
        return self.valor

    def abastecer(self) -> None:
        self.tipo = input("Olá, bem vindo ao posto Sheel, qual será o tipo de combustível?\n")
        self.preco = input(f'Qual o valor do litro do {self.tipo}?\n')
        self.quantidade = input(f"Qaual a quantidade que será abastecida?\n")
        self.calcular_valor(self.preco, self.quantidade)
        print(f"O abastecimento deu {self.valor} reais.\n")
```